# Internet Explorer - anchor active state doesn't trigger when a window pops up

Tags: css

I am creating my own custom styled Facebook connect button. When someone clicks on it, Facebook pops up a small window where the user can authenticate my website. The problem is, The active state of the anchor is never triggered on Internet Explorer 9. It's working on Firefox and Chrome. If I comment out the Javascript for popping up Facebook, the active state starts working. How do I make IE trigger the active state even if the anchor pops up a window?

**HTML**

```
<a class="facebookConnect">Login with Facebook</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.facebookConnect {
   background: red;
}

.facebookConnect:hover {
   background: blue;
}

.facebookConnect:active {
   background: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
$$('.facebookConnect').each(
   function(button) {
      button.observe( 
         'click',
         function() {
            FB.login();
         }
      );
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **a** tag is missing the required href attribute. Even if it's just a **href="#"**, it is needed. Do that and it will possibly work.

Comment: I don't need a href before this anchor doesn't go a web page. It runs javascript.

Comment: Yeah, but the href is mandatory for the **a** tag. IE sometimes breaks the code because of the lack of the attribute.